# How do I conditionally add JavaScript to the <head> tag of some pages?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

We are looking for a way to conditionally add `<script>` to the page in the `<head>` tag with the purpose of having setting pages where we can add URLs paths, and only to those pages. If possible, add it as the very first item in the `<head>` tag.

Is there a module or a recommended way to do this?

We initially thought to use the following code.

#### mymodule.module

```
function  mymodule_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/myscript';
}
```

#### mymodule.libraries.yml

```
myscript:
  version: 1.x
  header: true
  js:
    /path/to/file: { external: true }
```

Comment: I recommend looking at the Asset Injector module: https://www.drupal.org/project/asset_injector I think it will do everything you want.

Comment: @andileco Yes, we found that module to be useful for our needs. Glad I was able to find it with your help.